# WooCommerce: Get meta fields from product attributes on product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display a specific product attribute on my product page in WooCommerce.
But I want to show not only the name but some extra information like a description and an image.

At the moment I'm using `wc_get_product_terms` for that:

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_attribute', array( 'fields' =>  'all' ) ); if( $values ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-product-details>
        <div class="content">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <?php foreach ( $values as $term ) : ?>
                <li class="">
                    <?php $icon = get_field('pa_attribute_icon', 'pa_attribute_'.$term->term_id); if( !empty($icon) ): ?>
                        <div class="highlight-img"><img src="<?php echo $icon['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $icon['alt']; ?>" /></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="highlight-label"><?php echo $term->name; ?></div>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I have read, that `wc_get_product_terms` is deprecated. Is there a better/newer solution to display the attributes with the additional informations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wc_get_product_terms` is not deprecated. `woocommerce_get_product_terms` it is.